# nginx url proxypass with rewrite using rgex

Tags: nginx, web-server

Could you please someone guide me on this?
whatever string coming after `/api/(variable string)`, I need the same should reflect on my `proxy_pass` variable

```
location /api/.*{
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    **proxy_pass http://10.0.1.98:8080/latilla/.***;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 /;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to instead just do:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.1.98:8080/latilla/;
}
```

Including a uri in the proxy_pass will replace the matching portion of the location (as long as it's not a regex).

Comment: You should use trailing slashes in both `location` and `proxy_pass`

Comment: Good catch @AlexeyTen, updated